# PHP Validation error message order

Tags: php, validation

When a user submits the form, all the POST data gets sent across to salesforce. I am currently working on improving the validation process on the server.

When the user miss out the all the fields, the validation process picks up company name as the error message.

Is there anyway to place the validation in order e.g. if none of the fields are filled out, first name is the first error message shown.

Please review the code below.

**index.php**

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
<input type='hidden' name="lead_source" value="web-to-lead">
<input type='hidden' name="Campaign_ID" value="campaignid">
<input type='hidden' name="oid" value="uniqueid">
<input type='hidden' name="ididid" value="Grade 3 (Hot)">
<input type='hidden' name="retURL" value="www.niceic.com">
<input type="hidden" id="recordType" name="recordType" value="ididididid">
<input type='hidden' name="designgenieid" value="Design Genie Webinar">

<div class="errorMessage"><?php if(isset($error)){ echo $error; } ?></div>

<label for="first_name">First Name</label>
<input  id="first_name" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['first_name']; ?>" /><br>

<label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
<input  id="last_name" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['last_name']; ?>" /><br>

<label for="phone">Phone</label>
<input  id="phone" name="phone" size="20" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['phone']; ?>" /><br>

<label for="email">Email</label>
<input  id="email" name="email" size="20" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>"  /><br>

<label for="company">Company</label>
<input  id="company" name="company" size="20" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['company']; ?>"  /><br>

<label for="00ND0000005gYZo">Question<input id="00ND0000005gYZo" maxlength="80" name="00ND0000005gYZo" value="<?php echo $_POST['00ND0000005gYZo']; ?>" type="text">

<br><input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php

//Initialize the $query_string variable for later use
$query_string = "";



if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if ($_POST['first_name'] == "") {
        $error="Please enter in your first name<br>";
    } elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $_POST['first_name'])) {
                $error="Only letters and white space allowed<br>";
        }



    if($_POST['last_name'] == ""){
        $error="Please enter in your last name<br>";
        }elseif(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$_POST['last_name'])){
                    $error="Only letters and white space allowed<br>";
            }

    if($_POST['phone'] == ""){
        $error="Please enter in your phone number<br>"; 
    }elseif(preg_match("/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$/", $_POST['phone'])){
      $error="Please enter in a valid phone number<br>";    
        }

    if($_POST['email'] == ""){
        $error="Please enter in your email<br>";
    }else if(!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$_POST['email'])){
            $error="Please enter in a valid email address<br>";
        }

    if($_POST['company'] == ""){
        $error="Please enter in your Company details<br>";
        } elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $_POST['first_name'])) {
                    $error="Only letters and white space allowed<br>";
            }


    if(isset($error)){
        //echo $error;
    }else{
            if ($_POST) {

            //Initialize the $kv array for later use
            $kv = array();

            //For each POST variable as $name_of_input_field => $value_of_input_field
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

            //Set array element for each POST variable (ie. first_name=Arsham)
            $kv[] = stripslashes($key)."=".stripslashes($value);


            }


            //Create a query string with join function separted by &
            $query_string = join("&", $kv);
            }
            //Check to see if cURL is installed ...
            if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
            die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
            }

            //The original form action URL from Step 2 :)
            $url = 'https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8';

            //Open cURL connection
            $ch = curl_init();


            //Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($kv));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);

            //Set some settings that make it all work :)
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

            //Execute SalesForce web to lead PHP cURL
            $result = curl_exec($ch);

            //close cURL connection
            curl_close($ch);
    }

};


?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is to initialize the $error before you check and instead of setting it like

```
$error = "Please enter in your first name<br>";
```

You should only append all the errors to the string like this:

```
$error .= "Please enter in your first name<br>";
```

Your code should look like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$error = "";

if ($_POST['first_name'] == "") {
    $error .= "Please enter in your first name<br>";
} elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $_POST['first_name'])) {
            $error .= "Only letters and white space allowed<br>";
    }



if($_POST['last_name'] == ""){
    $error .= "Please enter in your last name<br>";
    }elseif(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$_POST['last_name'])){
                $error .= "Only letters and white space allowed<br>";
        }

...

if(isset($error) && trim($error) != ""){
    //echo $error;
}else{
....
```

Answer (score 2):

Tokk has answered your direct problem.

You could also add a last check to see if all POST variables are empty and overwrite your error.

However your validation code is reinventing the wheel, which is typically bad when dealing with production code.
I would suggest to take a look at php validation components which do your job but much better and safer.

See [Symfony Validation Component](http://symfony.com/components/Validator) or [Zend Filter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.filter.introduction.html)

(I know only symfony's one and it can be used standalone,Zend should be good too, but I am unaware if it need some prerequisites like Zend_Form etc.)

Answer (score -1):

If you want make these errors priority then you have to place first name validation in last means in place of company validation(Bottom to Top). Actual your variable $error is replacing with every validation so its picked up company validation. If you want to show all validation then make $error as an array Otherwise place validation from bottom to top.

For one erro at a time use below code

```
 if($_POST['last_name'] == ""){
    $error="Please enter in your last name<br>";
    }elseif(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$_POST['last_name'])){
                $error="Only letters and white space allowed<br>";
        }

if($_POST['phone'] == ""){
    $error="Please enter in your phone number<br>"; 
}elseif(preg_match("/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$/", $_POST['phone'])){
  $error="Please enter in a valid phone number<br>";    
    }

if($_POST['email'] == ""){
    $error="Please enter in your email<br>";
}else if(!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$_POST['email'])){
        $error="Please enter in a valid email address<br>";
    }

if($_POST['company'] == ""){
    $error="Please enter in your Company details<br>";
    } elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $_POST['first_name'])) {
                $error="Only letters and white space allowed<br>";
        }

if ($_POST['first_name'] == "") {
    $error="Please enter in your first name<br>";
} elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $_POST['first_name'])) {
            $error="Only letters and white space allowed<br>";
    }
```

To show all errors at a time use

```
 <?php

//Initialize the $query_string variable for later use
$query_string = "";



if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$error=array();

if ($_POST['first_name'] == "") {
    $error[]="Please enter in your first name<br>";
} elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $_POST['first_name'])) {
            $error[]="Only letters and white space allowed<br>";
    }

if($_POST['last_name'] == ""){
    $error[]="Please enter in your last name<br>";
    }elseif(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$_POST['last_name'])){
                $error[]="Only letters and white space allowed<br>";
        }

if($_POST['phone'] == ""){
    $error[]="Please enter in your phone number<br>"; 
}elseif(preg_match("/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$/", $_POST['phone'])){
  $error[]="Please enter in a valid phone number<br>";    
    }

if($_POST['email'] == ""){
    $error[]="Please enter in your email<br>";
}else if(!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$_POST['email'])){
        $error[]="Please enter in a valid email address<br>";
    }

if($_POST['company'] == ""){
    $error[]="Please enter in your Company details<br>";
    } elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $_POST['first_name'])) {
                $error[]="Only letters and white space allowed<br>";
        }



if(isset($error)){
    foreach($error as $er){
echo $er."<br/>";}
}else{
        if ($_POST) {

        //Initialize the $kv array for later use
        $kv = array();

        //For each POST variable as $name_of_input_field => $value_of_input_field
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        //Set array element for each POST variable (ie. first_name=Arsham)
        $kv[] = stripslashes($key)."=".stripslashes($value);


        }


        //Create a query string with join function separted by &
        $query_string = join("&", $kv);
        }
        //Check to see if cURL is installed ...
        if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
        }

        //The original form action URL from Step 2 :)
        $url = 'https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8';

        //Open cURL connection
        $ch = curl_init();


        //Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($kv));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);

        //Set some settings that make it all work :)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

        //Execute SalesForce web to lead PHP cURL
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        //close cURL connection
        curl_close($ch);


   }

};


?>
```

Comment: This solution would still only show one (the first) error